# Create excel workbook from byte array of sub part of existing excel file

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, xlsx

I would like to create a Apache POI excel workbook from the byte[] of partially read existing excel file. Please find the details as below

1. Download big excel file in multiple small parts from API. returns byte[]
2. Downloaded part-1 needs to convert to excel workbook and process the records
3. above will continue till the end of file

I am using Apache POI using Java but getting below exception
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file

```
byte[] downloadPart = downloadFile(rangeDetails);

InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(downloadPart);

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(targetStream);
```

Can someone please help me to create a new workbook for every sub part of big excel file.

Comment: Not possible as you want it. Apache poi needs a complete and valid excel file and not just parts of it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - Thanks. Which file format can help me with the above scenario? any idea?

Comment: Not a file format. You probably need a custom logic to read the parts that you get. Though they are usually XML to any XML parser would help